# Using VBA to subtract values for a column and paste it to next column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in VBA, I'd like to subtract partial values from Column B and paste it to Column A using VBA, any help would be appreciated.

Tab Name - Raw Data

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| ABCD | 000000000ABCD53453534543 |
| CDEF | 000000001CDEF999999999 |
| FGHJ | 000000002FGHJ5345435345 |

my VBA code as below:

```
SUB RecordType

with sheet("Raw Data")

With .range("A:A")

.Value = mid("B:B",10,4)

END WITH
END WITH
END SUB
```

Comment: You can't do it in one go like that. Why not use a formula?

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/use-evaluate-in-vba-instead-of-looping-through-cells/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Load data on Col B into an array
- Extract the substring and write to Col A

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.Offset property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144169)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes
    Set rngData = Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 0)
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        arrRes(i, 0) = Mid(arrData(i, 1), 10, 4)
    Next i
    rngData.Offset(, -1).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

---

You can get the expected output w/o formulas and coding

- Step1: input ABCD at cell A1
- Step2: Click `Flash Fill` ( or press <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> )

[image]